# How to add font ttf file in nextjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, fonts, next.js

I am new to Nextjs. I wanna add my custom fonts to my project. I am totally confused about how to do that(my fonts are in "public/fonts/"). my global.css file is this-

```
html,
body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, Segoe UI, Roboto, Oxygen,
    Ubuntu, Cantarell, Fira Sans, Droid Sans, Helvetica Neue, sans-serif;
}

a {
  color: inherit;
  text-decoration: none;
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

@font-face {
  font-family: "Avenir";
  src: url("../public/fonts/AvenirNextRoundedStd-Demi.ttf");
  src: url("../public/fonts/AvenirNextRoundedStd-MedIt.ttf");
  src: url("../public/fonts/AvenirNextRoundedStd-Reg.ttf");
}
```

and this is my next config file -

```
// next.config.js
const withCSS = require("@zeit/next-css");
module.exports = withCSS({
  /* config options here */
});
```

Answer (score 3):

You should refer to `public` directory as `/`. So, your CSS should be something like this:

```css
@font-face {
  font-family: "Avenir";
  src: url("/fonts/AvenirNextRoundedStd-Demi.ttf");
  src: url("/fonts/AvenirNextRoundedStd-MedIt.ttf");
  src: url("/fonts/AvenirNextRoundedStd-Reg.ttf");
}
```

But I think you are trying to add multiple weights of the font. So, shouldn't your CSS be like this?

```css
body {
  font-family: "Avenir", sans-serif;
}


@font-face {
  font-family: "Avenir";
  font-weight: 400;
  src: url("/fonts/AvenirNextRoundedStd-Reg.ttf") format('truetype');
}

@font-face {
  font-family: "Avenir";
  font-weight: 500;
  src: url("/fonts/AvenirNextRoundedStd-MedIt.ttf") format('truetype');
}

@font-face {
  font-family: "Avenir";
  src: url("/fonts/AvenirNextRoundedStd-Demi.ttf") format('truetype');
  font-weight: 600;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, now the error is not showing but all the fonts are unchanged

Comment: Did you update font-family in `body {}`? I updated the answer and added the body section, too.

Comment: Yes, I have but still no success. I also have added "next-fonts" to my next.config.js.. still no success

Comment: You shouldn't need `next-fonts` if you placed font files in the `public` directory.

Comment: I can send you my entire project file. please help me out... it's my 1st job, don't wanna loss it

Comment: I have added `format('truetype')` to `src`s in my answer, can you please try that too?

Comment: man you are a saviour... now it's showing. But the font-weight is not applying

Comment: Also, now everything is in cursive :(

Comment: There should be a problem about your font TTF files. I suggest you find an updated version of the font files, in OTF format if possible. And then use with `format('opentype')`. Also, please check this docs article: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/css-font-face